# How to restrict size of an XML list based on the size of another XML list in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1, xsd-1.0

I have an XML Schema, a snippet of which looks like the one below:

```
<xs:complexType name="Operation" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="inputFields" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="field" type="field" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="outputFields" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="field" type="field"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I want to put a restriction/validation that the size of the list `inputFields` and `outputFields` be equal.
How can I achieve that in the XML Schema itself?

Answer (score 2):

### XSD 1.1

You could do this via assertions in XSD 1.1 by constraining the count of the number elements in `inputFields` and `outputFields` to be equal:

```
<xs:assert test="count(inputFields/field) = count(outputFields/field)"/>
```

You'd place this on the element declaration containing both `inputFields` and `outputFields`.

### XSD 1.0

You cannot use `xs:assert` in XSD 1.0 and cannot express your constraint given your current XML design.  However, if you instead redesigned your XML to pair input and output fields together in the first place,

```
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="inputField" type="field"/>
                <xs:element name="outputField" type="field"/>
            </xs:sequence>
```

you'd naturally constrain their occurrence counts to be equal, and you'd be able to use XSD 1.0.